# How to get the content of groups of balanced parentheses

Tags: python, regex

text:

```
text1 = 'xx(aa)(bb)xx'
text2 = 'xx(aa(bb))xx'
```

expectation:

```
('aa', 'bb')  
('aa(bb)',  'bb')
```

My approach, but it does not meet expectations.

```
re.compile(r'\(\s?(.+?)\s?\)')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install the [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and use

```py
import regex

texts = ['xx(aa)(bb)xx', 'xx(aa(bb))xx']
rx = r'\(((?:[^()]++|(?R))*)\)'

for text in texts:
    print(regex.findall(rx, text, overlapped=True))
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##JY3BCoMwEETv@Yq9ZbdKL70J4j@U3tRCxNgGbBLWWLbQf0/VzmV48JiJn/QM/pKze8XACdg@rCiVrKQFami1CBpDOAwkokv4844794pls1h3iNhU7R2pL4ovNleiE3WklZoCw74Gzh@9VAq2RHY@4fF2npwfzTwjS3koJYS35dnEaMf6xqslyvkH). Output:

```
['aa', 'bb']
['aa(bb)', 'bb']
```

The `\(((?:[^()]++|(?R))*)\)` regex is a [common PCRE compliant regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35271017/3832970) that matches strings between nested paired parentheses, I added a capturing group  for contents in between the brackets.

To get all overlapping parentheses, the `overlapped=True` option is passed to `regex.findall`.